# codeigniter and youtube api - xml woes

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, youtube-api

I am working on a project that uses codeigniter and the youtube api, I make a request for a video, and I am getting some XML back, my issue is that I have no idea what to do with said XML, or more to the point how to parse it so I can get to the values I want, the XML I getting back it,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc</id>
    <published>2010-11-29T21:28:22.000Z</published>
    <updated>2011-03-14T12:01:51.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Travel' label='Travel &amp; Events'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Barney'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Harwood'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='Interview'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='children&apos;s'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='bafta'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='awards'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='2010'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='red'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='carpet'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='host'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='tv'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='television'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='show'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='presenter'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='prank'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='patrol'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='the'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='sorcerer&apos;s'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='apprentice'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='bbc'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='cbbc'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='bear'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='behaving'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='badly'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='nev'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='smile'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='totally'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='doctor'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='who'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='basil&apos;s'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='swap'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='shop'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='basil'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='brush'/>
    <title type='text'>Barney Harwood Interview</title>
    <content type='text'>Barney Harwood Interview - We talk to children's TV presenter Barney Harwood on the red carept, ahead of his duties as host for the Children's BAFTA Awards 2010 in London. Presented by Michael Kurn Camera and Post by Russell Nelson</content>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x33JD3-hXHc&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc/responses'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.ratings' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc/ratings'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.complaints' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc/complaints'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc/related'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=x33JD3-hXHc'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc'/>
    <author>
        <name>LeicesterSquareTV</name>
        <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/leicestersquaretv</uri>
    </author>
    <gd:comments>
        <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/x33JD3-hXHc/comments' countHint='5'/>
    </gd:comments>
    <yt:hd/>
    <media:group>
        <media:category label='Travel &amp; Events' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Travel</media:category>
        <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/x33JD3-hXHc?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;d=Ac2cvuTKQbM_TEZ_NAvfWNEO88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDm&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='150' yt:format='5'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v4.cache7.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAl3XKF_D8l9xxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQHNnL7kykGzP0xGfzQL31jRDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='150' yt:format='1'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v2.cache5.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAl3XKF_D8l9xxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQHNnL7kykGzP0xGfzQL31jRDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='150' yt:format='6'/>
        <media:description type='plain'>Barney Harwood Interview -We talk to children's TV presenter Barney Harwood on the red carept, ahead of his duties as host for the Children's BAFTA Awards 2010 in London. Presented by Michael Kurn
        Camera and Post by Russell Nelson
        </media:description>
        <media:keywords>Barney, Harwood, Interview, children's, bafta, awards, 2010, red, carpet, host, tv, television, show, presenter, prank, patrol, the, sorcerer's, apprentice, bbc, cbbc, bear, behaving, badly, nev, smile, totally, doctor, who, basil's, swap, shop, basil, brush
        </media:keywords>
        <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x33JD3-hXHc&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/x33JD3-hXHc/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:01:15'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/x33JD3-hXHc/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:00:37.500'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/x33JD3-hXHc/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:15'/>
        <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/x33JD3-hXHc/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:52.500'/>
        <media:title type='plain'>Barney Harwood Interview</media:title><yt:duration seconds='150'/>
    </media:group>
    <gd:rating average='5.0' max='5' min='1' numRaters='1' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
    <yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='1141'/>
</entry>
```

specifically how would I get the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start reading about [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

And if that doesn't cut it for you, you can find a more comprehensible, but a lot simpler, tutorial right [here](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using the library I developed. [Here is the link](https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library). If you are then there is an 'alt' parameter that you can pass into your library call that will let you specify how you want your data returned. If you set it to JSON then you can use the json_decode function built into PHP.

Even if you aren't using my library you can still use the alt parameter just specify it on your GET uri.